# Keras GRU после Dense

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

Прочитал статью, в которой исследователи использовали GRU после полносвязного слоя, с tanh активацией. Решил реализовать модель в keras, написав:

```
concated = layers.concatenate([meaning, form])
gen_dense = layers.Dense(gen_dense_dim)(concated)
gen_activation = layers.Activation('tanh')(gen_dense)
gen_gru = layers.GRU(gen_gru_dim, return_sequences=True)(gen_activation)
```

Где meaning и form - Dense слои.
На последней строчке получаю ошибку:
    'unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int''

Насколько я понимаю, проблема с размерностями, но я не знаю, как её исправить.

App: Добавил воспроизводимый пример на tensorflow:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
inp = layers.Input(shape=(16,))
den = layers.Dense(32)(inp)
act = layers.Activation('tanh')(den)
gru = layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True)(act)
```

Ошибка:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: можете привести в вопросе небольшой __воспроизводимый__ пример?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема действительно была в размерностях. Между Dense и GRU стоило поставить Reshape:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
inp = layers.Input(shape=(16,))
den = layers.Dense(32)(inp)
act = layers.Activation('tanh')(den)
res = layers.Reshape((32,1), inpupt_shape=(32,))(act)
gru = layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True)(res)
```